# Simple JQuery Drag and Drop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Okay, so I tried to make this  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/s9T4b/)

But when I go to the website where I am trying to make [this](http://bouncygames.org/scripts/testing.php), I can't drag it.

How come I can't drag or close this popup I made?

Comment: Your pop.js is not correct, it contains the css classes instead of JS Code and also put that reference below the jquery min and ui min files.

Comment: popup.js and popup.css are the same css file.

Comment: @j08691 I fixded that and it still wont work.

Comment: You seem to have removed the .js file and now your code to create the draggable is gone.

Answer (score 1):

In JSFiddle you're using jQuery v `1.7.2`, on your website v `1.3` - that's **ancient**. Just upgrade to the latest

To update put this in your file instead of the old references:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( "#myDialog" ).draggable({
        handle: "#title"
    });
    $( "#closeBtn" ).click(function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: replace the old reference with `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You didn't include your dragging script on your page - just jQuery and jQuery UI